# How to scrape xml feed with xmlfeedspider

Tags: python, xml, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape an xml file with the below format

**file_sample.xml:**

```
<rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
   <item>
       <title>SENIOR BUDGET ANALYST (new)</title>
       <link>https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=1</link>
       <pubDate>Wed, 18 Jul 2012 04:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
       <category>All Open Jobs</category>
   </item>
   <item>
       <title>BUDGET ANALYST (healthcare)</title>
       <link>https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=2</link>
       <pubDate>Wed, 18 Jul 2012 04:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
       <category>All category</category>
   </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

Below is my **spider.py** code

```
class TestSpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "testproject"
    allowed_domains = {"www.example.com"}
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.example.com/hrapp/rss/careers_jo_rss.xml"
        ]
    iterator = 'iternodes'
    itertag = 'channel'


    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        title = node.select('item/title/text()').extract()
        link  = node.select('item/link/text()').extract()
        pubdate  = node.select('item/pubDate/text()').extract()
        category  = node.select('item/category/text()').extract()
        item = TestprojectItem()
        item['title'] = title
        item['link'] = link
        item['pubdate'] = pubdate
        item['category'] = category
        return item
```

**Result:**

```
2012-07-25 13:24:14+0530 [testproject] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://hr.templehealth.org/hrapp/rss/careers_jo_rss.xml>
    {'title': [u'SENIOR BUDGET ANALYST (hospital/healthcare)',
               u'BUDGET ANALYST'],
     'link': [u'https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=1',
               u'https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=2'] 
     'pubdate': [u'Wed, 18 Jul 2012 04:00:00 GMT',
               u'Wed, 18 Jul 2012 04:00:00 GMT'] 
     'category': [u'All Open Jobs',
               u'All category'] 
      }
```

here as u can observe from the above result, all the results from the corresponding tags are combined in to single list, but i want to map according to their individual item tag like below as we do it for html scraping.

```
    {'title': u'SENIOR BUDGET ANALYST (hospital/healthcare)'
     'link': u'https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=1'
     'pubdate': u'Wed, 18 Jul 2012 04:00:00 GMT'
     'category': u'All Open Jobs'
      }
    {'title': u'BUDGET ANALYST'
     'link': u'https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=2' 
     'pubdate': u'Wed, 18 Jul 2012 04:00:00 GMT'
     'category': u'All category'
      }
```

How can we scrape xml tag data according to separate main tag like  item tag above.

Thanks in advance.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the use of [feedparser](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/):

```
feedparser.parse(url)
```

results in

```
{'bozo': 1,
 'bozo_exception': xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException("EntityRef: expecting ';'\n"),
 'encoding': u'utf-8',
 'entries': [{'link': u'https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=1',
   'links': [{'href': u'https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=1',
     'rel': u'alternate',
     'type': u'text/html'}],
   'tags': [{'label': None, 'scheme': None, 'term': u'All Open Jobs'}],
   'title': u'SENIOR BUDGET ANALYST (new)',
   'title_detail': {'base': u'',
    'language': None,
    'type': u'text/plain',
    'value': u'SENIOR BUDGET ANALYST (new)'},
   'updated': u'Wed, 18 Jul 2012 04:00:00 GMT',
   'updated_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=18, tm_hour=4, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=200, tm_isdst=0)},
  {'link': u'https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=2',
   'links': [{'href': u'https://hr.example.org/psp/hrapp&SeqId=2',
     'rel': u'alternate',
     'type': u'text/html'}],
   'tags': [{'label': None, 'scheme': None, 'term': u'All category'}],
   'title': u'BUDGET ANALYST (healthcare)',
   'title_detail': {'base': u'',
    'language': None,
    'type': u'text/plain',
    'value': u'BUDGET ANALYST (healthcare)'},
   'updated': u'Wed, 18 Jul 2012 04:00:00 GMT',
   'updated_parsed': time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=7, tm_mday=18, tm_hour=4, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=200, tm_isdst=0)}],
 'feed': {},
 'namespaces': {},
 'version': u'rss20'}
```

Comment: Wow! thanks very much that helped a lot. But actually we need to select the the respective values of the tags by searching right. But is there anyway to display the tags and tag values only

Comment: Doy you mean something like this: `[entry.tags[0]["term"] for entry in feedparser.parse(open("/tmp/feed.rss")).entries]` => `[u'All Open Jobs', u'All category']`?

Comment: No actually what my idea is when we run a xml url with some code it should automatically parse the tags and map with their values dynamically(Irrespective of knowing the tags and retrieving the values from the tags manually), but the above code u have given is acceptable.

Comment: Whether there are any other libraries or modules for doing the same

Answer (score 4):

Try changing your **itertag** from `itertag = 'channel'` to `'itertag = 'item'`

Answer (score 2):

Just change itertag = 'item'.

If you refer to the documentation of [parse_node](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.XMLFeedSpider.parse_node) method, it states that the method is called for the nodes matching the provided tag name (itertag). In you case it is 'item'(child node to 'channel' rootnode).